# Large negative numbers format

Tags: javascript

How do I format a negative number to be like this?

```
-5000 -> -5 k
-1000000 -> -1 M
-2700000000 -> -2.7 B
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `-50 k`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function you can use:

```
function format_number(num) {
    var identifiers = ['k', 'M', 'B'];
    var identifierLengthMinusOne = identifiers.length - 1;
    var identifierOffset = -1;
    var isNegative = (num < 0);

    num = Math.abs(num);

    while (num >= 1000 && identifierOffset < identifierLengthMinusOne) {
        num /= 1000;
        identifierOffset++;
    }

    return (isNegative ? num * -1 : num) + (identifierOffset > -1 ? ' ' + identifiers[identifierOffset] : '');
}
```

---

```
> format_number(-500)
"-500"

> format_number(-50000)
"-50 k"

> format_number(-50000000)
"-50 M"

> format_number(-50000000000)
"-50 B"

> format_number(-50000000000000)
"-50000 B"
```

Comment: When I place `-50000000000000000000000000` as the argument, I get `"-50.00000000000001 undefined"`. Floating point fun again ;)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Sorry about that - when optimizing the code I missed out the variable check (`identifierLengthMinusOne` should be `identifierOffset < identifierLengthMinusOne`). You'll still get `"-50000000000000010 B"` though (thanks, javascript..).

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
function intToString (value) {
    var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
    var suffixNum = Math.floor((""+value).length/3);
    var shortValue = parseFloat((suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum)) : value).toPrecision(2));
    if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortNum = shortValue.toFixed(1);
    return shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
}
```

usage:

```
intToString (-5000)
```